# Fetching ipv4 address dynamically in android

Tags: android

I am using the below mentioned URL to connect to wamp server from my android device. I am using volley to send values using POST method.

```
String LoginURL="http://"+"192.168.1.33"+"/Beacon/Login.php";
```

Now here **192.168.1.33** is the IPV4 address that is obtained from the ipconfig/all command in the cmd prompt of my laptop which is hosting the wamp server.

My question is , whether there is a way to dynamically fetch this from the code running on my android device.

I used the below piece of code but it is fetching the IP of the device that runs the application which is **192.168.1.35**

```
WifiManager wifiMan = (WifiManager) MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInf = wifiMan.getConnectionInfo();
int ipAddress = wifiInf.getIpAddress();
final String IpAd = String.format("%d.%d.%d.%d", (ipAddress & 0xff),(ipAddress >> 8 & 0xff),(ipAddress >> 16 & 0xff),(ipAddress >> 24 & 0xff));
```

Is there any solution for this. I could not find any satisfactory answer in any other thread.

Comment: Answer is:  You cannot get your computers IP from android. You can get your own ip not servers. You have to specify server's id yourself

Comment: Is there any other workaround for this problem?